# Dynamic Programming for LCS problem

Tags: dynamic-programming

I understand that in Dynamic Programming approach the subproblems are solved in a particular order from smallest to largest. In LCS how the subproblems sizes are defined and in which order it is solved.

Comment: What is LCS, pray tell?

Comment: Probably [Longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence). The question should be answerable from reading the Wikipedia article and working through the step-by-step worked example. If not, please ask a specific question about what part of the recurrence you don't understand.